# Node module 'request' returns incomplete html

Tags: node.js, request

I'm hoping to use the following snippet in a scraper to pull stats from remote radios on a network:

```
var request = require('request');
var radioURL = '192.10.1.65';
request.get({
    url: pageURL
}, (error, response, html) => {
    console.log(html);
```

The console outputs the following html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="2.22.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="2.22.js">"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="show('viewPage=10');">
    <div id="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="reboot"><center><input type="button" value="Reboot" onclick="javascript:show('reboot=1');"></center></div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

The payload I'm interested in parsing out resides in the div tag with id='content'. Inside there is a form, and inside the form is a table with all the data I'm after. The image below shows an inspection of the page expanded to see 'Voltage' with a corresponding value inside of td tags. I've tried different combos of headers in request, as well as timeouts thinking that network latency was part of the issue. How do I get to elements below the div element?

Thanks.

[inspection of elements below div element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN67O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `request.get()` retrieves the RAW HTML that the web server sends to the browser.  That's what you get.  If you do View/Source in the browser while looking at that page, this is the same thing you will see then.

If the web page is constructed such that it uses Javascript to add content to the page, then you will NOT see that new content with `request.get()` because no Javascript is run when retrieving data with `request.get()`.  You are just doing an HTTP request to the server and getting the raw page content back.

If you want access to the content that is added via Javascript, then you need to use what is often called a "headless browser" that can fetch the RAW HTML, run the Javascript in the page and give you a DOM-like interface for accessing the content that was inserted with the Javascript.

You can see a listing of headless browser modules that you can use in nodejs here: https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers.  I don't have personal experience with any of them, but the ones I see mentioned the most here on stack overflow are Nightmare, X-Ray and PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

For site scraping, i am a massive advocate of x-ray. It's well documented, but in your case you would basically go

```
xray('http://192.10.1.65', 'form-elements-you-are-targetting')(fn)
```

https://github.com/matthewmueller/x-ray

It's very, very, good.